# Territories claimed by the PRC but not the ROC

Tags: china, borders, taiwan, territorial-dispute

The Republic of China (ROC, often known simply as "Taiwan") and the People's Republic of China (PRC) both claim to be the sole legitimate government of all of China.  But the two polities have different notions of what "all of China" means in geographical terms.

There is clearly a great deal of territory that the ROC considers, or once considered, to be part of China that the PRC does not.  (For instance, [until about 20 years ago](https://web.archive.org/web/20090210192036/http://www.taipeitimes.com/News/archives/2002/10/11/0000175237), the ROC considered the entirety of Mongolia to be its own territory.)  But conversely, are there any territories that the PRC *does* claim to be part of China that the ROC *does not* claim to be part of China?  If so, what are they?

Comment: It seems to me Taiwan actually [recognized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia%E2%80%93Taiwan_relations) Mongolia as an independent country, albeit in 2002, but since then "excludes Mongolia from the official maps of the Republic of China".

Comment: Fair enough; I will amend the question accordingly.  Though I'm sure there are other territories claimed by the ROC and not the PRC.

Comment: I'm not sure what Taiwan's stance is on the sea/ islands emcompassed by the 'nine-dash line' but that could be a candidate.

Comment: "both claim to be the sole legitimate government of all of China." In what way does the ROC still make that claim? When was the last time they said it? From what I have seen the ROC no longer considers itself the government of China. I think to get an accurate answer you need to be clear what you mean by "claim".

Comment: @Readin Notwithstanding the fact that they no longer make a big deal about it, the claim is still valid insofar as it hasn't been formally disclaimed. The constitution, as amended, still refers to the "existing national borders" from 1947 and distinguishes between the "free" and occupied areas. And certain official maps, such as the one on the emblem of the Marine Corps, still show the greater borders. Nonetheless, feel free to pretend my question was written at the most recent time the ROC explicitly affirmed its claim.

Comment: The [RoC's constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_the_Republic_of_China) still assumes that it governs all of China, being based on the 1930s Chinese constitution, although it's not clear to me what specific claim the current government makes. I'd be surprised if they renounced all claim until the PRC did likewise re Taiwan. (For comparison, the Republic of Ireland claimed sovereignty of the North until 1998, 76 years after partition and independence of the south, so it's not terribly unusual to have such claims).

Answer (score 3):

Tibet, *possibly*, according to a 2000 LA Times [article](https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-2000-may-03-mn-25985-story.html):

> But Taiwan’s Democratic Progressive Party--whose leader, Chen Shui-bian, will be sworn in three weeks from now as the government’s first non-Nationalist president--makes no such claims for Tibet.
>
> “The DPP will continue to support the Tibetan people’s struggle for freedom,” declared a party position paper in 1997. “Tibet is neither a part of China nor under the jurisdiction of the [Nationalist] government in Taiwan.”

It's less than 100% clear though what happened after the DPP came to power. It's also difficult to measure this more objectively than at the level of those statements since neither Tibet nor Taiwan are UN-recognized.

Also, according to one Wikipedia page, the Taiwan MFA [map](https://www.mofa.gov.tw/CountryInfo.aspx?CASN=5&n=5&sms=33&s=30) is no longer claiming Arunachal Pradesh as part of China. I cannot read Chinese myself as to the finer print of this map, but clearly Arunachal Pradesh is in green there and not otherwise delineated from India.

[image]

On the other hand, that map does include Tiben in some kind of China, but I don't know what the label reads.

---

Also, PBS [reminds](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/politics/why-relations-between-china-and-taiwan-are-so-tense) us that even in 2022:

> Taiwan’s KMT-drafted constitution continues to recognize China, Mongolia, Taiwan, Tibet, and the South China Sea as part of the ROC.

But as I noted in some comments under the Q, that constitution appears to have been *de facto* ignored/violated with respect to Mongolia since 2002, as Wikipedia [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongolia%E2%80%93Taiwan_relations):

> Relations changed in 2002, ninety-one years after Mongolia's first declaration of independence. At the time, the Republic of China still did not recognize Mongolia as an independent country; official maps of the Republic still showed Mongolia as its territory. When the Executive Yuan under the Democratic Progressive Party administration announced that Mongolian nationals would be entitled to visas rather than entry permits when traveling to Taiwan, the same as individuals from foreign countries, the Kuomintang-controlled Legislative Yuan criticized the implementation of the decision, as they had not been consulted in this regard. Later, representatives of the two governments agreed to open offices in each other's capitals; ROC's office in Ulaanbaatar was opened in September of that year. ROC's Ministry of the Interior then decided to discontinue including Mongolia on its official maps of ROC territory, and on 3 October 2002, the Ministry of Foreign Affairs announced that ROC recognizes Mongolia as an independent country.

Comment: According to Google Translate, the label reads "Mainland China".